# C Socket, Add header before data stream

Tags: c, sockets

I'm sending bytes through sockets and that works fine. Now in terms of transfer files, I need to send file size before sending actual data. So I come up a idea that send file size as a header before file data.

For example, if file data is `"1234"`, then socket will send 4 bytes of its length (which is 4) before `"1234"` and there will be 8 bytes sending through socket. First 4 bytes contains data length, and the rest of bytes are actual data.

I can convert int into bytes (i.e. char array) by:

```
bytes[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
bytes[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytes[3] = n & 0xFF;
```

The problem is I can't add this 4 bytes before actual data:

```
char *data = [Actual data of file];
char *buffer = malloc(4 + strlen(data));
strcpy(buffer, bytes);
strcat(buffer, data);
```

The result of this is that `bytes[]` are gone, and `buffer` has exactly same data as `data`

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to prepend the length bytes to your data buffer.  Use a separate buffer.  Then you can `send()` the length buffer before you `send()` the data buffer.  Even better, you can store the data length in a 32-bit `int` or `uint32_t`, using `htonl()` to arrange the bytes in network byte order, and then `send()` that directly without copying it to its own buffer.  This becomes easier to manage if you wrap your send logic in a function, eg:

```
void sendData(void *data, uint32_t datalen)
{
    uint32_t len = htonl(datalen);
    send(socket, &len, sizeof(len), 0);
    send(socket, data, datalen, 0);
}
```

```
char *data = [Actual data of file];
uint32_t datalen = [Actual length of file];

sendData(data, datalen);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm assuming that you know what you are doing with data, and that it is a nul-terminated string, and that you don't want to send the terminator (because you don't allocate space for it in your buffer). What you want could be done as follows:

```
size_t len = strlen(data);
char *buffer = malloc(4 + len);
memcpy(buffer, bytes, 4);
memcpy(buffer + 4, data, len);
```

Note that your bytes are NOT a string, therefore you do NOT want to use string functions like `strcpy` or `strcat` on them. [`memcpy(dst, src, len)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) just copies exactly `len` bytes from `src` to `dst`, not caring about the actual contents such as nul-terminators.

Comment: yeah, i think memcpy could work. Thanks. What do you mean by nul-terminated string? I think terminator is already at the last character of `data` string.

Comment: The last character of a C string is the nul-terminator `'\0'` (or just `0`). However, this is not part of the string itself: `"hello"` is `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}`. Note that this string consists of 6 characters even though `strlen("hello")` is 5.

Comment: I wander if there is more efficient way to use instead of memcpy ?